# Jetpack Compose PaddingModifier cannot be cast to androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the HorizontalPager from Accompanist library, and inside one of the tabs, I have a LazyColumn with different types of items.
Now normally, all works fine, but as soon as the data changes and I scroll through the LazyColumn, I get this crash:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingModifier cannot be cast to androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl
```

I'm using Jetpack Compose `1.2.1` with Kotlin `1.6.21`.

Update:
I had an item in my LazyColumn:

```kotlin
Divider(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 8.dp))
```

Removing the padding from this solved the issue. But I would still like to know the actual cause of this issue.

Comment: I don't think so that only adding padding to the Divider will cause the issue. Please add more context to it, share the code of that `Composable`, if you can.